# Caracteres especiales en Android con teclado físico

Tags: android, keyboard

He diseñado un USB teclado por hardware.

Lo he probado en Windows y Android y funciona muy bien.

El problema son los caracteres especiales, por ejemplo, para escribir la letra Ñ, el hardware emula un 'ALT + 1 + 6 + 5 ' y en Windows aparece la letra Ñ.

He probado esto en Android y lo que aparece es la letra N.

¿Alguien sabe como se envía caracteres especiales con un teclado por hardware en Android?

Comment: Una pregunta un poco boba, ¿El idioma del teclado/teléfono está en inglés o español?

Comment: Es un teclado USB que hice con un microcontrolador 32 bits. Por ejemplo, para enviar la letra Ñ debes enviar alt + 1 + 6 + 5, la pregunta es comos e hace lo mismo con Android:  Acá puede ver un video de mi teclado:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_1kujqf8pU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Si conectas un teclado USB que tiene la tecla Ñ a un dispositivo USB, no funciona, no tiene nada que ver si el teclado es para español o inglés. Los teclados físicos son solo para Windows, por eso ahí si funciona la letra Ñ u otros caracteres no ingleses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias aquellos que respondieron, pero muchos no entendían que la pregunta se trataba de un teclado real, físico, con cable USB para conectar a un PC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo conectas a un dispositivo Android (no necesariamente un móvil) funciona, pero las teclas especiales como la Ñ no funcionaban, ni haciendo al combinación ALT + números. Pero ya descubrí como hacerlo.

Es la combinación de la tecla ALT Gr con la letra especial, por ejemplo ALT GR más N, produce la Ñ.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Solo sé hacerlo en Word, fuera de Word no fuciona.

Escribes el código unicode del carácter que quieres y luego pulsas alt-X.

Por ejemplo, yo uso mucho el guión largo. Así que escribo, tal cual y en números dentro del archivo de word:

2014

y con el cursor a la derecha del 4 pulso alt-x y te lo convierte en guión largo.

También funciona al revés:

A (aqui pulsas alt-x) -> 0041

Es fácil.

Comment: Puede que esto sea un "hack", pero no responde a la pregunta del OP: _¿Alguien sabe como se envía caracteres especiales con un teclado por hardware en Android?_ Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No es un hack, sino una función de Word. Yo hace tiempo que busco lo mismo que tú y lo único que pude encontrar fue esto.

Comment: Hombre, estoy hablando de un teclado Físico, real, de aquellos que tienen cable USB, para conectar a un PC. Si lo conectas a un dispositivo Android (no necesariamente un móvil) funciona, pero las teclas especiales como la Ñ no funcionaban, ni haciendo al combinación ALT + números. Pero ya descubrí como hacerlo

Comment: ¿Podrías comentar cómo lo hiciste y así nos ayudas a todos? Gracias.

Comment: @Tirso Está como solución a esta pregunta, y esta pregunta la hice es porque hice un teclado real (hardware) con un microcontrolador vía USB y no sabía como "enviar" la Ñ cuando presionaban dicha tecla, acá el video del protitpo. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_1kujqf8pU